# how can i solve the following issue in android regarding "iptables"?

Tags: android, iptables

This is the error i am getting in logcat:

```
runIptablesCmd(): failed /system/bin/iptables -t raw -A bw_raw_PREROUTING ! -i lo+ -m owner --socket-exists res=768
```

After issued `strace -c netd` i got the following things. please suggest me to proceed further.

```
iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `raw': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a `ramdisk` issue.

Check and make sure your `ramdisk (mainly init.rc)` has the necessary parts for the `mdns` service. You can see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/b8d3d0e905b82d3fee42d955968c4f57c1776086/rootdir/init.rc) that there are additions to the `netd` service (these mdns services weren't in Android versions before Jellybean) that have mdns added to it and there is also an mdns service as well at the bottom of the `init.rc` I linked to earlier.

Add those two parts to the `init.rc` and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: i have mdns services. i am running android on virtual box(NAT).